# Can I send Saml2AuthnRequest without subject property? 'Subject' is not supported by Azure AD

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, saml-2.0, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

The Saml2 Authn Request include a subject property which apparently azure does not like. Is there a way of modifying the request xml to not include the subject property or any other work around?

I am getting the following error:

```
AADSTS900236: The SAML authentication request property 'Subject' is not supported and must not be set.
```

This is what it says from Microsoft docs

```
Subject
Don't include a Subject element. Azure AD doesn't support specifying a subject in AuthnRequest and will return an error if one is provided.

A subject can instead be provided by adding a login_hint parameter to the HTTP request to the single sign-on URL, with the subject's NameID as the parameter value.
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-sign-on-saml-protocol#subject

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just leave the `Subject` property empty in the `Saml2AuthnRequest`. Then the `Subject` property is not send.

In the TestWebAppCore sample [AuthController.cs](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebAppCore/Controllers/AuthController.cs#L36) you would remove this line:

```
Subject = new Subject { NameID = new NameID { ID = "abcd" } },
```